# What is "protein redox conformation"?

Tags: redox, biochemistry, terminology, proteins

From an article by Frye et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spen.2020.100835)]:

> Reduced glutathione (GSH) is the major intracellular redox buffer and is essential in free radical scavenging, redox homeostasis, **maintenance of protein redox conformation** and regulation of redox sensitive enzyme activity.

What is "maintenance of **protein redox conformation**"? Is it just fancy phrasing for "keeping proteins properly reduced, but not too much reduced, and properly oxidized, but not too much oxidized?

#### Reference

1. Frye, R. E.; Rossignol, D.; Scahill, L.; McDougle, C. J.; Huberman, H.; Quadros, E. V. Treatment of Folate Metabolism Abnormalities in Autism Spectrum Disorder. *Seminars in Pediatric Neurology* **2020**, 100835. DOI: [10.1016/j.spen.2020.100835](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spen.2020.100835).

Comment: Ha, ASD seems to be quite a popular topic these days:) The term also appears in a 20 year-old publication https://doi.org/10.1046/j.1432-1327.2000.01601.x.

Comment: It seems like poor wording. It probably means "maintenance of equilibrium between protein redox conformations".